# Should i use Boon Json parser in Android and if Yes then How?

Tags: android, json

I have gone through Boon json Github repository but the question here is I use it in Android because the developer itself says that Android is blind spot.So i am little bit confused on using this.And if Yes, then how would i do that? I have downloaded there source but how can i add it as a library in Android Studio?

Any help would be really appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer Gson. It's light weight and easy to use.

If you have a simple Pojo you can simply call:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
String s gson.toJson({POJO Object HERE});
```

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-gson-to-work-with-json-in-your-android-apps/
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks..but i was going through stats and it looks Jackson is really better than Gson but i am expecting more than Jackson then Boon json comes up in the picture